# Ubuntu 22.04 - apt 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I'm having troubles with apt and the sources list. I keep getting 503 errors, even though the ur'l work with curl. ofther repo's (zabbix for example) does work fine.

There is NO proxy settings needed, nor are they setup. Any tips on this are welcome. I've reviewed several other articles regarding 503 errors with APT but none solve my issue.

So any tips are welcome.

```
root@geda-zabbix:~# apt update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix-agent2-plugins/1/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.4/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The URL works with Curl:

```
root@geda-zabbix:~# curl http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /ubuntu</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /ubuntu</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="4"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="dists/">dists/</a></td><td align="right">2022-10-27 17:39  </td><td align="right">  - </td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="indices/">indices/</a></td><td align="right">2023-04-20 07:27  </td><td align="right">  - </td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="ls-lR.gz">ls-lR.gz</a></td><td align="right">2023-04-20 07:28  </td><td align="right"> 24M</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="pool/">pool/</a></td><td align="right">2010-02-27 06:30  </td><td align="right">  - </td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="project/">project/</a></td><td align="right">2013-06-28 11:52  </td><td align="right">  - </td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="ubuntu/">ubuntu/</a></td><td align="right">2023-04-20 07:35  </td><td align="right">  - </td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="4"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at archive.ubuntu.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
root@geda-zabbix:~#
```

I've allso tried switching to a local mirror (ftp.belnet.be) and i get the same issue.
So i switches back but left the local mirror commented.

Sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted


deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

When i download a package manually from the repo with wget, this works:

```
root@geda-zabbix:~#  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/net-snmp/libnetsnmptrapd40_5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6_amd64.deb
--2023-04-20 10:17:10--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/net-snmp/libnetsnmptrapd40_5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6_amd64.deb
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 185.125.190.39, 185.125.190.36, 91.189.91.38, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|185.125.190.39|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24936 (24K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘libnetsnmptrapd40_5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6_amd64.deb’

libnetsnmptrapd40_5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6_amd64.deb  100%[=============================================================================================================>]  24.35K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s

2023-04-20 10:17:10 (1.48 MB/s) - ‘libnetsnmptrapd40_5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6_amd64.deb’ saved [24936/24936]

root@geda-zabbix:~#
```